# Run docker image with docker-compose

Tags: c#, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have my simple app in C# that connect with postgreSQL.
I would like to create image with this app and just run with docker.

Everything is ok when I use:

```
$ docker build
$ docker run postgres
$ docker run my_app
```

Additionally, there is everything ok, when I use compose from application directory:

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up
```

But is there any chance for use docker-compose for image that I built previous?

I would like to publish this image to my repo and somebody else from my team just download and run this image (app + database).

When I do compose-build and next compose run my_app I have exception during connecting to database:

```
dbug: Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection[3]
      Opening connection to database 'POSTGRES_USER' on server 'tcp://postgres:5432'.

Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (No such device or address) ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: No such device or address
```

My current docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  web:
    container_name: 'postgrescoreapp'
    image: 'postgrescoreapp'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/postgrescoreapp
    ports:
     - "5001:5001"
    depends_on:
     - "postgres"
    networks:
      - postgrescoreapp-network

  postgres:
    container_name: 'postgres'
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - postgrescoreapp-network

networks:
  postgrescoreapp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: You should be able to create a docker compose config that uses your own images, sure. Either use the `build` or `image` attributes to build your images or use a predefined one (that you host in your repo): https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: I have already use it in my docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: What I am doing wrong that my app can not connect with postres, when I do docker-compose build and docker run my_app

Comment: Then I suggest that you add that to your question, along with your Docker Compose file, and the command that you use to run... At the moment, it doesn't include any of that.

Comment: I have added some details.

Comment: Could you share postgresql's logs too please?

Comment: I have the same idea like you, but it seems we can't do that. What docker-compose did is to run multipile images together. Our idea is to have just one image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should build the image with this name: (registryName:RegistryPort)/imagename:version

```
$ docker build -t myRegistry.example.com:5000/myApp:latest .
$ docker build -t myRegistry.example.com:5000/myDb:latest .
```

Now add these lines to the docker-compose file :

```
Myapp:                                                    
  image: myRegistry.example.com:5000/myApp:latest 

MyDb:                        
  image: myRegistry.example.com:5000/myDb:latest
```

And then push it :

```
$ docker push myRegistry.example.com:5000/myApp:latest
$ docker push myRegistry.example.com:5000/myDb:latest
```

Your mate should now be able to pull it now

```
$ docker pull myRegistry.example.com:5000/myApp:latest
$ docker pull myRegistry.example.com:5000/myDb:latest
```

Comment: Yes, it will run too. But I would like to run only with docker-compose. One command should run my app with database

Comment: then you just have to do "docker-compose up -d", it'll run both apps

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You can use previously created image from `repository` via `docker compose`.

**Example:**

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    image: farhad/my_app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - testnetwork
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    networks:
      - testnetwork
networks:
  testnetwork:
    external: true
```

**Example Explaination:**

I'm creating a container named `app` from my repository and another container named `postgres` via library `postgres` image.

Please note you need to create an push your custom image to repository first.

I'm using `user-defined` networks here, You need to create `testnetwork` before `docker-compose up`.

Comment: I have this docker-compose.yml file with similar structure. My app run, but there is an exception during connection to postres. My connection string is: "User ID=postgres;Password=password;Server=postgres;Port=5432;Database=POSTGRES_USER;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;" It works with two cases as I mention above.

Comment: from docker-compose, or docker build? docker-compose works fine but only when I run this command from application directory